# Cannot run Displays from System Settings

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an Intel i6700k with an Nvidia GTX 970 video card. After the install I did 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade' and 'apt-get dist-upgrade'. I can boot the machine and login, but when I click 'Displays' from the 'Systems Settings ' window, Ubuntu reports (occasionally) an internal error, and never creates the Displays window.

I also can't seem to get Keyboard shortcuts to work.

What should I do?

UPDATE: the Ubuntu error window said this:

```
unity-control-center crashed with SIGABRT in g_assertion_message()
```

Comment: I think with 6th generation processors and newer NVIDIA cards, Ubuntu 16.04 is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there any way to know that for sure?  I mean, 99 percent of it works.  It looks like only unity-control-center is problematic.

Comment: Well I read the 6th generation processors don't work correctly with 14.04's default kernel version, but that may have changed. I do know, however, that newer versions of Ubuntu have better support for newer hardware.